# flexable summing in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table as follows:

```
def, amount , date
add    5       1.1.15
add    5       2.1.15
add    1       3.1.15
remove 5       4.1.15
add    4       4.1.15
make   8       4.1.15
add    5       4.1.15
```

I need to write a query which perform the action of def (add/remove) and present it, if there are other actions it should present the last row value:

```
def, amount , date        , afterdone
add    5       1.1.15           5
add    5       2.1.15           10            / 5+5
add    1       3.1.15           11            / 10+1
remove 5       4.1.15            6            /11-5
add    4       4.1.15           10            /6+4
make   8       4.1.15           10            / 10 the value row above
add    5       4.1.15           15            /10+5
```

you can assume that the rows are already ordered as needed.

I thought of doing something with window function using

```
ROWS between UNBOUNDED PRECEDING and CURRENT ROW
```

but It doesn't mulipule operation (it wouldn't know what is add,remove,make...)

How do I do that?

**EDIT:** to make it simple....  assume this is the table of origin. where id defines who comes before who.

```
id    def, amount , date
 1   add    5       1.1.15
 2   add    5       2.1.15
 3   add    1       3.1.15
 4   remove 5       4.1.15
 5   add    4       4.1.15
 6   make   8       4.1.15
 7   add    5       4.1.15
```

Comment: .  SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no such thing as assuming "that the rows are already ordered as needed".  You need a column specifying the ordering.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this with window functions, *assuming that you have a column specifying the ordering*.  SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  You need a column for the ordering.  So:

```
select t.*,
       sum(case when def = 'add' then amount
                when def = 'remove' then - amount
                else 0
           end) over (order by date, id)
from atable t;
```

This assumes that `id` is a secondary ordering column after `date`.  But, if `date` has a time component, then this is not necessary.